# Chrome App Webview Back/Forward Mouse Buttons

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app, history

In my app back/forward mouse buttons are disabled and I can't find how to enable it. In the `manifest.json` no one property which can enable this buttons.
How to provide users with the ability to manage a history without any additional buttons?

Comment: Define "disabled", how are you trying to use them?

Comment: This buttons are disabled in default Chrome or Webview settings. I want to enable it but don't know how.
Sorry for incorrectly expressed.

Comment: So, trying to reconstruct your use case (and it really should be in the question), do you need them for a webview?

Comment: I need this buttons in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation is [disabled for Chrome apps completely](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated), so Back/Forward events never have any effect.

Since those mouse buttons don't seem to generate any events that can be detected, it seems unlikely that you can detect that at all.

As (weak) evidence, Google's own ["web browser" app sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webview-samples/browser) does not support them.

Comment: If navigation is disabled why `Backspace` and `Shift+Backspace` works fine?